# Development items disappeared from software center

Tags: software-center, libraries, development

In Ubuntu 14.04, I could search the software center for items like "libsdl" and get a link at the bottom to show the development packages.

In Ubuntu 16.04, this option to show development packages is gone. Is there any GUI at all now to find these items, or do I have to do it all in the terminal now?

Answer (score 1):

This is the package that I needed: https://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/

For Ubuntu simple install with

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```